# Cannot access any web pages from web browser?

Tags: windows-xp, webpage

At home, I am using wireless connection and I can access any web sites perfectly. However, when I brought my computer to my company network, it can connect to the access point but cannot access any web pages. This happened about two days ago.

I have tried to bring my laptop to the IT support in the company but they had no ideas. I haven't installed any new software or hardware devices.

Any ideas?

I am using Windows XP and the Chrome browser. I have also tried Firefox and Internet Explorer but no luck.

Comment: Way too little information. Is the system able to access any of the company's internal networked resources when on the company network? If so, what works vs. maybe what doesn't work?

Comment: Does the company use a proxy server?

Comment: yes, I can access the internal website

Answer (score 2):

If you can access internal websites, more than likely the issue is that your server has a Proxy Server (like @tombull89 said) and need to set that up in your Internet Explorer settings (Tools > Internet Options > Connections > Proxy settings). Check that against a workstation that can connect to the internet.